# DAC MCP4802 datasheet corner frequency

Tags: arduino, dac, cutoff-frequency

The [MCP4802 8bit DAC datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002249B.pdf) states that (1/f) CORNER = 400 Hz. Does it mean that even if I input to DAC 1kHz (using Arduino Nano) signal it will be attenuated due to the 400Hz cutoff of the DAC?

Answer (score 3):

That's a noise spec.  See Fig. 2-13.  It does not affect signal bandwidth.